# Junit test for Map<String, Set<Object>>

Tags: java, hashmap, set, junit5

I'm trying to write few asserts in a test case.
My test returns the following.

```
Map<String, Set<Object>> results;

class Object {
String name;
Set<String> elements;
}

String objectName = "test";
```

I tried the following assert but getting an error cannot resolve method name getName() in Set.

```
assertThat(result.values()).hasOnlyOneElementSatisfying(r -> {
        assertThat(r.getName().isEqualTo(objectName);
});
```

Any help with where i'm going wrong will be much appreciated.

Results contains:

```
<"TestKey", Set<TestObject>>
TestObject.name = objectName ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
assertThat(result.values()).hasOnlyOneElementSatisfying(r -> {
    assertThat(r).extracting(ObjectClass::getName).containsAnyOf("test1");
});
```

One sample example is given below

```
@Test
void sampleTest()
{
    Map<String, Set<ObjectClass>> result = new HashMap<>();
    Set<ObjectClass> objectClassSet = new HashSet<>();
    objectClassSet.add(new ObjectClass("test1", new HashSet<>()));
    objectClassSet.add(new ObjectClass("test2", new HashSet<>()));
    objectClassSet.add(new ObjectClass("test3", new HashSet<>()));
    result.put("something", objectClassSet);


    assertThat(result.values()).hasOnlyOneElementSatisfying(r -> {
        assertThat(r).extracting(ObjectClass::getName).containsAnyOf("test1");
    });
}
```